# In Ubuntu windows and menus in GNOME looks like KDE

Tags: gnome

In Ubuntu 12.10 I run KDE once (usually I use GNOME), after that all windows, menus, icons and so on looks like KDE, not GNOME theme. How enable again GNOME look?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Ubuntu 13.10) when I tried kubuntu-desktop today, and I found two annoying packages in my terminal with some regex → gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen. So I tried to remove them with the following command and it works.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen
```

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Sorry, but I change my OS with hardware, new installation works fine. Thank you for answer! :)

Comment: is there any way to keep that installation and change the config?

Answer (score 0):

Remove from your $HOME directory any file that is of the form.gtkrc After removing such files, go back into your Appearance settings and change your theme to Ambiance or Radiance, apply, then move onto your preferred theme.